# CSS - my page is too long

Tags: html, css, magento

There's a ton of blank space at the bottom of my page - http://shop.promaholics.com/? (It loads slow on the dev server, sorry).

I've been through the CSS lots looking for min-height type attributes but can't find any that would be causing this. Perhaps I've gone blind.

Any ideas what I can do to reduce that blank space at the bottom?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its the UL with class `level0`

right... you have a **dropdown menu** in "favours" in the menu that is causing the problem... its got too many elements (see if you mouseover "favours" it will be the length of your page).

Its because the script isn't hiding the element - its just moving it 10000 px to the right... :/ can you change this by using `display:none;`?

Comment: Thomas Clayson is right. I've hidden the `<ul>` element with Firebug and the blank space has disappeared.

Comment: Good catch. I'm going to have to point this out to the theme designer. Thank you so much for helping me out :-)

Comment: it is DEFINITELY a bad idea to have that many elements in a drop down list - thats ridiculous. You should probably have the top 5 elements, and then the rest in a "more" link or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Change to this...

/* 2nd Level */

```
#nav ul { position:absolute; width:15em;  display:none; border:1px solid #452915; }
```

/* Show menu */

```
#nav li ul.shown-sub,
#nav li div.shown-sub { display:block; top:39px; z-index:999; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with disabling javascript and it removes the blank space at the bottom. I'm not sure in which script it's affecting it yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the class from the `main-container col1-layout` div then the blank space is greatly reduced - try looking for stray CSS in that class.

**Edit:** Wait, that's just because the images are no longer displaying inline. Whoops.